# Query on feature layer and draw a point on feature with matching OBJECTID

Tags: json, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I have a JSON file with data as:

```
    [{
        "data": [{
            "assetID": 1,
            "colorCode": 3
        }, {
            "assetID": 2,
            "colorCode": 1
        }, {
            "assetID": 3,
            "colorCode": 4
        }, {
            "assetID": 4,
            "colorCode": 2
        }, {
            "assetID": 5,
            "colorCode": 3
        }, {
            .
            .
            .
        "assetID": 1000,
        "colorCode": 2
    }]
}]
```

where, 
assetID is unique (upto 1000)...
colorCode is a random number between 1 to 4... and each colorCode corresponds to any unique color.Like,

colorCode 1, color Green...
  colorCode 2, color Orange...
  colorCode 3, color Yellow...
  colorCode 4, color Red...

I have created a simple webmap in ArcGIS online with one tile layer and one feature layer. Now, I have to write a code in JS where when the feature's OBJECTID matches the assetID, a point should be drawn there in the color corresponding to the colorCode on the map.
Like, for assetID 1 colorCode is 3, so at feature with OBJECTID 1 on the map, a point should be drawn there in green color and so on.
I have created the JSON file and the webmap, but I am really new to all this ArcGIs and dojo and I am really at a loss where to proceed next.

Comment: so you have only features whose the `OBJECTID`  is between 1 -- 4 that are colored ??

Comment: Its the colorCode that can be 1,2,3 or 4...each corresponding to a specific color. The OBJECTID and assetID can be upto 1000. We just have to match the assetID with the feature's OBJECTID and draw the point in that color

Comment: so it's limited to max 1000 ( I mean not dynamic assetIDs ) !

Comment: Yeah...I have assetID till 1000

Answer (score 0):

How are you hosting the application. Is it just a webmap in ArcGIS online or you using WebAppBuilder or you have a custom web application. All these factor determine whether you can customize your map or not.

Also, your layer is it a FeatureLayer or a Map Service. or just graphic data. If it is graphic data its lot easier to make the customization. Let me know more details so that I can provide you with specific answer.

Take a look at this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50558/customizing-arcgis-online-application-template-and-uploading-it-back-to-arcgis-o
it provides information on how you can customize webmap.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Its just a webmap in ArcGIS online, and a pretty basic one at that. The Layer is a feature layer. I dont want to customize it... I want to know how to access the layers of a webmap and perform a Query Task on it.

Comment: I know this must seem quite easy, but as I said its all new for me... and I am really puzzled

Comment: Take a look at javascript api.https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_webmap.html

Comment: I did it myself.Thanks for the link.It helped.